# what are the steps to configure ubiquity router

Tags: ubiquity

steps to Enable DHCP on the ubiquiti router(edgerouter/poe) and connect my laptop to it with a specific

> network and subnet

Answer (score 0):

Use the wizards which are available to use when you log in to the router. Default IP is 192.168.1.1 and the best wizard for you is WAN+2LAN2.